# Problem with NDSolve: the function diverges

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to numerically simulate heat flux in a 3d power cable model that i build. Essentially the equation is:

[image: Temperature and Power equations]

I can get an analytic solution from Mathematica easily and when i plot T(x) i get no trouble (putting the constraint T'(x)=0 and T'(l)=0):

[image]

second picture shows T'(x)=0

[image]

Because i want to add some nonlinear thermal behavior i had to use NDSlove, and first i try to solve the same equation that i wrote before to see if it works:

```
sol = NDSolve[{-T[x] + \[Tau] + 
 P[x]*(Subscript[\[Rho], t]) + (Subscript[\[Rho], 
   t])/(Subscript[\[Rho], c])*T''[x] == 0, T'[0] == 0,  T'[l] == 0}, T[x], {x, 0, l}]
```

and the numerical solution give me this:

[image]

i can't undertand what's the deal here and why it doesn't converge!!

Here complete Code:

```
P[x_] := 3*r*(\[Kappa] + \[Lambda]*((x - l/2)/(l/2))^2)^2
T0 = P[0]*Subscript[\[Rho], t]
\[Kappa] = 1597.14
\[Lambda] = 1788 - \[Kappa]
r = 0.0000133
\[Tau] = 20
Subscript[\[Rho], t] = 0.54877
Subscript[\[Rho], c] = 0.332502
l = 100000
\[Alpha] = 0
sol = NDSolve[{-h[x] + \[Tau] + 
     P[x]*(Subscript[\[Rho], t]) + (Subscript[\[Rho], 
       t])/(Subscript[\[Rho], c])*h''[x] == 0, h'[0] == 0, 
   h'[l] == 0}, h[x], {x, 0, l}]
```

Comment: Works for me with my chosen parameters: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BP3lR.png -- You'll need to give complete code to get much help.

Comment: complete code added

Comment: Parameters not defined. How can we verify the solution?

Comment: In your picture analytical solution does not satisfy boundary conditions `T'[0] == 0,  T'[l] == 0`

Comment: yes it's satisfied, slope of T(x) goes to zero at 0 and l but you can't see it from the picture because T''[x] is zero at 13 and graphic is from 0 to 100000, this is the reason why you can't see it. anyway i need help!

Comment: i added the parameters at the end of the post

Comment: Consequently, the solution consists of two thin boundary layers and a core. Numerically, to obtain such a solution will be difficult.

Comment: I found a solution, but it does not look like an analytical one.

Comment: The fact is that the heat flux radially is 10^5 greater than longitudinal one. Prob this is the fact that leads to ill-conditioned solution. Investigatin in this leads to think about a non-convergent part of the solution that the NDSolve can't eliminate. Other people here have this problem, in analitycal version i didn't encounter any problem

Comment: can you put an image of it?

Answer (score 1):

1)Increase the order of the equation to solve the Dirichlet problem; 2) map the solution to the interval (0,1) by replacing `x->l*x`; 2) use the method of the false transient. Then the system of equations and the solution are

```
P[x_] := 3*r*(\[Kappa] + \[Lambda]*(2*x - 1)^2)^2

\[Kappa] = 1597.14;
\[Lambda] = 1788 - \[Kappa];
r = 0.0000133;
\[Tau] = 20;
rt = 0.54877;
rc = 0.332502;
l = 100000;
k = rt/rc/l^2;

eq = {-h[x, t] + D[P[x], x]*rt + k*D[h[x, t], x, x] - 
     D[h[x, t], t] == 0};
ic = h[x, 0] == 0;
bc = {DirichletCondition[h[x, t] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[h[x, t] == 0, x == 1]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, h, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 20}] 
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(h\), \(x\)]\)"}]

Plot[Table[sol[x, t], {t, 5, 20, 5}], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(h\), \(x\)]\)"}]
```

[image: fig1]

The solution of the problem reaches a stationary state already at `t>1`. Integrating over `x`, we find the solution to the original problem up to a constant

```
hS[x_] := NIntegrate[sol[x1, 20], {x1, 0, x}]

{Plot[hS[x], {x, 0, .01}], Plot[hS[x], {x, 1 - .01, 1}], 
 Plot[hS[x], {x, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x", "T"}]}
```

[image: fig2]

We choose the integration constant = 90, then the solution is similar to the analytical one. Note that with numerical integration on the right-hand boundary, when `x-> 1`, a numerical instability arises, although the function `sol[x1,20]` is rather smooth.
[image: fig3]